# How to ask `WSL` to remember variables when called by `bash -c`?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

It seems `WSL` doesn't remember variables when called by `bash -c`. For example, in Powershell I input:

```
bash -c 'a=100; echo $a'
```

It returns nothing, but in bash the same command will return `100`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need upgrade your system.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]

C:\Users\Reker>bash -c 'a=100;echo $a'
100
```